# Applying bash operations to first level subfolders of a folder

Tags: bash, shell-script

Asume I have this folder structure:

```
parent1
   |----- subfolder1
              |--- x
              |--- y
   |----- subfoldern
              |--- x
              |--- y
parentn
   |----- subfoldern1
              |--- x
              |--- y
   |----- subfoldernn
              |--- x
              |--- y
```

I need a bash script that receives as input a parent folder and applies some fixed operations in the first level subfolders. E.g:

```
$> myScript parent1
```

This would get the first level subfolders (subfolder1 and subfoldern) and for each of the call the fixed set of operations, e.g:

1. ls subfolder1
2. du subfolder2

Could you provide a bash script that implements this functionality?

IMPORTANT: If one of the operations fails the folder is skipped and the script moves on to the next folder.

Comment: This is not really a script writing service. What have you tried and which part of your solution do you have issues with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can iterate only directories using a slash at the end of the pattern.
- You can make a sequence of command abort on the first faiure by using `&&` between commands.

So all this boils down to:

```
for d in parent/*/ ; do ls "$d" && du "$d" ; done
```

Answer (score -1):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

folder=$1

# Find the first level of folders within the specified folder
for child in $(find $folder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
    # If the command fails, # bash will carry on to the next folder anyway :)
    echo $child  # Replace with magic command
done
```

Comment: You missed double quotes at many places.

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)